# How to pass authentication in Flickr without opening a browser?

Tags: authentication, flickr

I'm developing Flickr client. It's a desktop application.

I need to pass authentication without opening a browser i.e. I have 2 fields for login and password and when user press "Log in" button all authentication steps should be performed behind the scenes.

Flickr API actually offers to open a default browser and let user pass authentication manually.

What is the way of this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.howto.desktop.html

Here's what I think is a similar question on the FlickrNET API Discussion board:

http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=76155

Comment: That desktop authentication flow has been deprecated I think